# Interpretations of a weighted adjacency matrix's eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose that I have weighted undirected graph $G$, and the corresponding adjacency matrix which is a symmetric matrix $A$.

Suppose that the edge between node $i$ and $j$ has weight $w_{ij}$, then 
$$
A_{ij} = A_{ji} = w_{ij}
$$

The diagonal $A_{ii}$ can consist of arbitrary real numbers.

Because $A$ is symmetric, it can be written as 
$$
A=\sum \sigma_i v_i v_i^T
$$
where $\sigma_i$ is an eigenvalue, $v_i$ is an eigenvector, and eigenvectors are orthogonal.

When we consider a 0-1 adjacency matrix indicating whether or not there is an edge, there are a lot of results from [spectral graph theory](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/).

But there doesn't seem to be much results when we consider a weighted adjacency matrix.

I'd like to know if there are interpretations of these eigenvalues and eigenvectors in terms of $G$'s properties.

Comment: But aren't you then just interested in eigenvalues of symmetric matrices?